# add header id or any data to nestjs axios request dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, nestjs

I have a controller

```
Post : /post
```

its can be called anytime
each time its called I should add a request-id and authorization to the header.

for authorization is easy to add because its should be in all request that going from this controller so I used axios interceptor

```
  axios.defaults.headers.common[
        'Authorization'
      ] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = `application/json`;
```

but how can I add an header per flow  , per controller call , so in each controller call the header will have "req-id: uuid()". per each request that go out to external api.

but when there is another call during the previous call I need to create a new request id offcourse

for now i created it manually  in the controller:

```
 async post(){
   reqId = "uuid"
   await service.start(reqId)
 }

 in  each function  i added manually the header to axios

  const headers = {
      'req-id': reqId
  }
```

then it will be passed for all function as a parameter . i don't want it as a function param and don't want to duplicate the code

how can I do it dynamically without passing this data for all functions ?

using interceptor in axios is for all request
I need it per controller call
thanks

Comment: check interceptors [axios doc](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

Comment: @AminTaghikhani interceptor on axios will affect all requests , i need it per flow , what will happen if i will got another request and then the first request wlill do the second call to the external api